# File Script Programming Im trying to set up my file script program to open my CWD

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to set up my file script program to open my CWD by entering in my terminal python3 -d Directory_commands.py /Users/file

Here is my code. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
The argument in my program  (-d) inside my terminal and the script should open that directory by default. Otherwise, my script should open the default folder where my scripts are run.
When I run my command python3 -d Directory_Commands.py, it begins to execute line 54. I'm not sure why I am getting this result here is my code:

```
import sys
import os 
import shutil
sys.path 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if "-m" not in sys.argv:
        privilege_level = sys.argv[sys.argv.index("-m") + 1]
    else:
        privilege_level = sys.argv[sys.argv.index("-m") + 1]
        if privilege_level != "basic" and privilege_level != "elevated" and privilege_level != "admin":
            print("Invalid privilege level. Please specify basic, elevated, or admin")
    if "-d" not in sys.argv: 
        starting_directory = sys.argv[sys.argv.index("-d") + 1]
    else:
        starting_directory = sys.argv[sys.argv.indez("-d") + 1]
        print("Please enter Directory")

    if ".." in starting_directory:
        print("Cannot move up the filesystem using ..")
        exit()
    if "-d" in starting_directory
        try:
            os.chdir(starting_directory)
        except:
            print("Please specify a directory to move to.")
    else:
        starting_directory = os.getcwd()


    if "-m" in sys.argv and privilege_level == "basic":
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        print("Current Working Directory %s" % cwd)
        change_dic = input("Would you like to change the directory?")
        if change_dic == "yes":
            direct = input("Enter Diectory:")
            mode1 = 456
            os.makedirs(direct, mode1)
            print(os.listdir())
            print(os.system("ls -l"))
    if "-m" in sys.argv and privilege_level == "elevated":
       cwd = os.getcwd()
       print("Current Working Directory %s" % cwd)
       change_dic = input("Would you like to change the directory?")
       if change_dic == "yes":
            direct = input("Enter Directory:")
            mode1 = 456
            os.makedirs(direct, mode1)
            print(os.listdir())
            print(os.system("ls -l"))
            x = os.stat(direct)
            print(x)
       chanf = input("Would you like to copy a file or directory? yes or no:")
       if chanf == "yes":
           file1 = input("Enter File's name:")
           new_file = input("Enter path you would like to store the copied file:")
           shutil.copy2(file1, new_file)
    if "-m" in sys.argv and privilege_level = "admin":
        cwd = os.getcwd()
       print("Current Working Directory %s" % cwd)
       change_dic = input("Would you like to change the directory?")
       if change_dic == "yes":
            direct = input("Enter Directory:")
            mode1 = 456
            os.makedirs(direct, mode1)
            print(os.listdir())
            print(os.system("ls -l"))
            x = os.stat(direct)
            print(x)
       chanf = input("Would you like to copy a file or directory? yes or no:")
       if chanf == "yes":
           file1 = input("Enter File's name:")
           new_file = input("Enter path you would like to store the copied file:")
           shutil.copy2(file1, new_file)
           shutil.move(file1)
```

Comment: You could start by explaining what this is *supposed* to do and what it is doing instead.

Comment: The other argument in my program should take (-d) inside my terminal  and the script shouldl open that directory by default. If not, my script should open the default folder where it runs my scripts.

Comment: When I run my command python3 -d Directory_Commands.py, the "-m" function generates an error when I try to run the python3 command

Comment: What is *the "-m" function*?

Comment: What is the name of the file this script is in?

Comment: The -m function is the module name and the Direct_commands.py

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
if "-m" not in sys.argv:
    privilege_level = sys.argv[sys.argv.index("-m") + 1]
```

But since `"-m"` isn't in the list, calling `index` to find it will raise an error.